# How to read directory without executing the directory?

Tags: permissions, 20.04, files, directory

Suppose i have directory `/home/me/okay` which have permission as shown below :

```
drwxr-xr-x 1 nizarpermanahadi nizarpermanahadi 4096 Jul 24 17:39 okay
```

After that i tried to change it with `chmod -x okay` command.
And now the permission had changed like this :

`drw-r--r-- 1 nizarpermanahadi nizarpermanahadi 4096 Jul 24 17:39 okay`

Now the directory only can be read or written. When i tried to read it. The terminal showed like this :

```
ls: cannot access 'okay/dalam.cpp': Permission denied
total 0
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? dalam.cpp
```

I want to read the directory without executing it and see the list. Can i do that?... if yes, how to do that?

Comment: You need the `x`-permission to be able to enter the directory. If you cannot enter the directory, you can't see the content of the directory and you cannot write (add, remove, rename) files in it.

Comment: @mook765 Thank You very much....